# Подсветка синтаксиса в JetPack?

Tags: wordpress, cms

Я решил воспользоваться встроенным в Jetpack *markdown*.

Если я пишу кусок кода, вот так:

````
```css
#button {
    border: none;
}
```
````

То никакой подсветки синтаксиса нет. Хотя форматирование и не портится и рамочка есть. Никаких других плагинов у меня нет. Ну и сам по себе markdown работает, звёздочки становятся болдом, решётки - заголовками.

Что я делаю не так?

Вот здесь обещано, что подсветка должна быть: https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown-quick-reference/

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про блог на платформе wordpress.com? Или про личный сайт на основе WordPress?

Comment: Речь про собственный сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о сайт на основе WordPress, а не о блоге на платформе wordpress.com, то из коробки работают лишь несколько тегов:

- asterisk (*) или a dash (-) маркированый список
- ввод 1. или 1) нумерованый список
- начать параграф с 2 до 6 решеток (#) заголовки разного уровня
- начать с символа больше (>) цитата

Тут на [видео](https://make.wordpress.org/core/files/2015/07/Editor-patterns-4.3-Beta-2.mp4?_=1) показано

Расширенный маркдаун в джетпаке надо активировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в [мануале](https://jetpack.com/support/markdown/) нигде не написано, что должна быть подсветка синтаксиса, вы путаете с wordpress.com, скорее всего.

Comment: Он у меня, вроде бы, активирован :(

В той ссылке на мануал, что ты привёл, где-то в середине написано:
"Jetpack uses Markdown Extra... See the WordPress.com Markdown Quick Reference page"
И если в этот самый Quick Reference кликнуть, то открывается https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown-quick-reference/, где и упоминается "Syntax highlighting".
Поэтому я думаю, что подстветка таки должна быть!

Comment: Так вы ожидаете подсветку синтаксиса в TinyMCE или на клиентской стороне?

Comment: На клиентской. Я ожидаю, что "посетитель" сайта увидит кусок раскрашенного кода. Если я этот код соответствующим образом обозначу, в процессе написания поста.